# Why is the TimeOfDay property truncated when a DateTime is passed to a new controller method?

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core

I have several dates in a SQL table that represent when files are uploaded from our application.

[image: SQL Dates]

In my code I have logic present to determine various things that should happen if 1 file exists, multiple files, etc.  One of those things is that if multiple files exist, the user is able to select any number of them for processing.

The code from my controller that handles the case of multiple files is below.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SelectFilesToProcess(int Id, string ClientConnectionString)
    {
        FileSelectionToProcess files = new FileSelectionToProcess();
        files.ClientID = Id;
        files.ConnectionString = ClientConnectionString;
        List<DateTime> uploadDates = _clientProcessingService.GetFileUploadDates(ClientConnectionString);
        foreach (DateTime date in uploadDates)
        {
            files.FileDatesToProcess.Add(new FileDateToProcess { FileDate = date });
        }
        return View(files);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SelectFilesToProcess(int Id, FileSelectionToProcess Model)
    {
        DateTime dateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        //Foreach date, import to CurrMo
        foreach(var fileDate in Model.FileDatesToProcess)
        {
            if(fileDate.IsChecked)
            {
                _importProcessing.InsertPOSImportedToCurrMo(Model.ConnectionString, dateAdded, fileDate.FileDate);
            }                
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Processing", new { Id, IsProcessing = false });
    }
```

This is the action called if there is more than 1 file.  I query the DB to get all of the dates and add them to a list of a complex type I made that stores a DateTime and a bool to determine which files were checked.  This `FileSelectionToProcess` type is my model in the view.

As I debug through this, I am able to see that my list of DateTime values contain the time of day so I can directly compare them to the timestamp in the database (which I use later to migrate data to different tables).

[image: Values are shown in debug]

But as soon as I select the dates I want to process and post the form, the `TimeOfDay` property seems to just clear itself and I lose that data, which now causes my stored procedure to not find a direct match in the DB and processes no data.

[image: TimeOfDay is gone]

View code and values present while debugging:

```
<body>
<h3>Select the imports you would like to process.</h3>
<form method="post">
    <div class="container-fluid col-lg-12 pt-3">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ClientID" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ConnectionString" />
        <table class="col-lg-12 table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>File</th>
                    <th>Details</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.FileDatesToProcess.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.FileDatesToProcess[i].IsChecked" type="checkbox" /> @Model.FileDatesToProcess[i].FileDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.FileDatesToProcess[i].FileDate">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="View Details" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue Processing" title="Click to continue to next step of processing" class="btn btn-light col-lg-3" />
</form>
```

[image]

Why does this happen and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: _"as I select the dates I want to process and post the form"_ - is the full date data including milliseconds stored in the form?

Comment: @stuartd Yes.  Edited a screenshot in

Comment: The most important code is missing here, namely the code of the view. We don't see how you store the values in the html document and how you send it back to your application. Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: @NineBerry Added view code and a screenshot of the value present in debug.

Comment: @Mkalafut your problem is exactly that in the linked duplicate.

Comment: An explanation for the downvotes would be appreciated.  I have full code samples and a clear problem I'm trying to solve.  When I made the question there was nothing showing up in my search prior to posting nor the suggested questions while I was writing it out so I apologize for not being able to hunt down a 10 year old post with only 1 common tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after some more searching I made the following changes.  Check the question and answer edits if you're curious about how I solved this before.

The model class I am using has a `List<DateToProcess>` That class was previously a single bool to determine if the value was checked and a DateTime.  I've now added a `long FileDateTick` property.

My view now has the following:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.FileDatesToProcess[i].FileDateTick" value="@Model.FileDatesToProcess[i].FileDate.Ticks" />
```

The controller action now parses each sent DateTime (in ticks) and makes a new DateTime which is sent to the stored procedure.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SelectFilesToProcess(int Id, FileSelectionToProcess Model)
    {
        DateTime dateAdded = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime fileDateFromTicks;
        string timeSpan;
        //Foreach date, import to CurrMo
        foreach (var fileDate in Model.FileDatesToProcess)
        {
            if(fileDate.IsChecked)
            {
                timeSpan = fileDate.FileDateTick.ToString();
                fileDateFromTicks = new DateTime(long.Parse(timeSpan));
                _importProcessing.InsertPOSImportedToCurrMo(Model.ConnectionString, dateAdded, fileDateFromTicks);
            }                
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Processing", new { Id, IsProcessing = false });
    }
```

Comment: Specifying the date format like this can be dangerous when then the code that parses the string back to a DateTime expects dd/MM instead of MM/dd. Result could be a wrong date value.

Comment: @NineBerry As per your comment and other information I found, I changed the answer.